# Espresso: Ui Watcher

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have used UiAutomator in the past. It will not do what I need now, so I am using [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/). One thing I loved about UiAutomator is the ability to create a UiWatcher. I have many dialogs that appear at random times.

So my question is how could I create a "watcher" that will handle the appropriate dialog if appeared? I have thought about creating a loop that checks for it, but will that be too CPU expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Espresso. Generally, conditional logic in tests is undesirable - you should control the environment (device) on which your tests execute so you do not get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Unexpected behavior is a connection lost dialog. It is expected, but not desired.